# List of Dictionary to xlwt

Tags: python, dictionary, xlwt

I have a list of **dictionary** and i want to convert it to excel using **xlwt**. I'm new to xlwt. Can you help me? Im using it as a function to receive list of dict and convert it to excel and then return. I have this list of dict.

```
{'id':u'1','name':u'Jeff'}

 {'id':u'2','name':'Carlo'}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make a worksheet. Then use [`Worksheet.write`](https://secure.simplistix.co.uk/svn/xlwt/trunk/xlwt/doc/xlwt.html?p=4966#xlwt.Worksheet.write-method) to fill a cell.

```
data = [
    {'id':u'1','name':u'Jeff'},
    {'id':u'2','name':'Carlo'},
]

import xlwt

w = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = w.add_sheet('sheet1')

columns = list(data[0].keys()) # list() is not need in Python 2.x
for i, row in enumerate(data):
    for j, col in enumerate(columns):
        ws.write(i, j, row[col])

w.save('data.xls')
```

Comment: there is an error. it says Unexpected data type <type 'instancemethod'>

Comment: @Nethan, Did you run above code as is? Otherwise, please show your code.

Comment: i think its in my list. I tried using a static list of dictionary and it worked. Anyway thank you so much for helping me.

Comment: @Nethan, Show your code so that I can check what's going on in your code.

Comment: Hello, how can i add a title at the top before adding the values below?

Comment: @Nethan,  `w.write(0, 0, 'id'); w.write(0, 1, 'name')` before the loop. You should adjust the outer loop: `for i, row in enumerate(data, 1):`

Answer (score 6):

If somebody need version with HEADERS:

```
import xlwt

w = xlwt.Workbook()
ws = w.add_sheet('sheet1')

columns = list(data[0].keys())

# write headers in row 0
for j, col in enumerate(columns):
    ws.write(0, j, col)

# write columns, start from row 1
for i, row in enumerate(data, 1):
    for j, col in enumerate(columns):
        ws.write(i, j, row[col])

w.save('data.xls')
```